# Custom popup using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to develop one filter in angularJs without using jquery. I am using custom directive to create one popup including checkbox. I have 2 doubts

**1.** Here I have 2 popup which I created using `ng-repeat` and I am passing some arguments in directive. If I pass simple string like bellow it will work properly

```
      <input checkbox-all="0-isSelected-id1"  class="clsInput" />
      app.directive('checkboxAll', function () {
      return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

         //here we can split this string 
         var parts = iAttrs.checkboxAll.split('-');
        });
```

But If I pass like this

```
      <input checkbox-all="{{$index}}-isSelected-id{{$index}}"  class="clsInput" />
      app.directive('checkboxAll', function () {
      return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

         //it will come undefined
         var parts = iAttrs.checkboxAll.split('-');
        });
```

I need to pass that index to that directive because this all code is inside one `ng-repeat`.

**2.** This two popup have same class and different id, I want to show this popup on click of 2 `div`. I want to do this without using jquery. on each click I want to set two styles to that popup(left and top for positioning that div in proper place)

**requirement**

[image]

[image]

Here I added my code, it is not perfect

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/renjithgovind/wev7s0ba/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/westlife_8/wev7s0ba/8/)**

To pass the index to a directive, there is no need to pass the index in an attribute. `$index` is already defined in the scope, you access it in the `checkboxAll` directive by `scope.$index`.

```
app.directive('checkboxAll', function () {
return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
var arrayContent=scope.mainList[scope.$index].list;

iElement.attr('type','checkbox');
iElement.attr('value','All');
//iElement.attr('id','All'+parts[2]);//check this id in design
iElement.bind('change', function (evt) {
var selectedval=evt.currentTarget.value;
  scope.$apply(function () {
    var setValue = iElement.prop('checked');
    angular.forEach(arrayContent,function(v){
        v.isSelected=setValue;
    });
  });
});
```

As for popup behaviour, I have added `div.subpart1` as a child of `div.sub1`. `div.subpart1` has `position:absolute`, so you can set the `margin-left` property to show it as a popup.

And to control visibility of the popups, I have added an array `$scope.IsVisible=[false,false]`, which has the visibility states of all popups.

The HTML is here:

```
<div class="sub1" >
<div class="subpart1" ng-repeat="val in mainList" ng-click="click($event,$index)" >
  <div id={{val.name}} class="mainPopup" ng-show="IsVisible[$index]" >
    <div class="rowSep">
  <input checkbox-all class="clsInput" /> 
       <div class="sub" ng-click="testa($event,val.list)" parent="Allid{{$index}}"> All</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="elem in val.list" class="rowSep">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="elem.isSelected" class="clsInput" /> 
      <div class="sub" ng-click="testa($event,val.list)"> {{elem.desc}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks..we can use this same concept in my design also...thanks for your support..

Answer (score 0):

Use this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mortezaQo/TKVH6/2642/) to check all,

**HTML**

```
<div>
<ul ng-controller="checkboxController">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /> Check All
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in Items">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" /> {{item.Name}}
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module("CheckAllModule", [])
.controller("checkboxController", function checkboxController($scope) {


$scope.Items = [{
    Name: "Item one"
}, {
    Name: "Item two"
}, {
    Name: "Item three"
}];
$scope.checkAll = function () {
    if ($scope.selectedAll) {
        $scope.selectedAll = true;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.Items, function (item) {
        item.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
    });

};
```

});

Comment: sorry u didn't understand my question